# Some of the keys r,q were not working, works only with Shift ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Randomly <kbd>r</kbd> key on keyboard doesn't work on the gnome terminal. It works only with <kbd>Superkey+r</kbd>.

Googled it and checked the key map bindings for <kbd>r</kbd> key using *dconf* editor. No shortcut has been mapped to it. checked event trace using `xev` command, no event has been generated for <kbd>r</kbd> key.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231307/key-for-the-letter-o-stopped-working-works-only-with-shift-linux

From the above link tried `killall gnome-settings-daemon` makes the <kbd>r</kbd> keys work. I try to understand the process behind it, however unable to get it. Please some one help me on this.

What makes the <kbd>r</kbd> key not work before killing the gnome-settings-daemon?

Comment: If you unplug the keyboard and plug it again, without killing any process, does the `r` key work?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani tried unplug the keyboard and plug it again , however **r** key doesn't works. Same keyboard check with windows it works fine. No problem with keyboard.